# sim800l obtengo caracteres especiales

Tags: arduino

tengo un problema con la placa Arduino mega y el modulo SIM800L conecto en los pines RX y TX del modulo y cuando ingreso al monitor serial me devuelve estos caracteres que podrá ser ?

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  Serial3.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
  
  if(Serial3.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial3.read()); // Lee desde el sim800l e imprime por el Monitor Serial.
  }

  if(Serial.available()) {
    Serial3.write(Serial.read());
  }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El monitor lo tienes a 9600, el script está a 115200

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta está en tu mismo fragmento de código e imagen:

En tu código tienes configurado tu frecuencia con 115200 baudios:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  Serial3.begin(115200);

}
```

pero en tu imagen se puede apreciar que el monitor está configurado para 9600 baudios(abajo a la derecha, la segunda opción)

Comment: si tienes razón lo cambie porque estaba probando con diferentes bbaudios pero nada el resultado es el mismo e probado con varios sim800l tengo 4 y todos dan el mismo resultado y lo peor de todo es que estaba funcioando bien de repente sale asi

Comment: aqui esta otra publicación que realice en ingles donde si esta acorde la imagen con el codigo  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416250/arduino-mega-sim800l-special-characters

Answer (score 0):

Después de tanto buscar y mirar en el osciloscopio he encontrado la solución,
En caso de que esté utilizando un convertidor reductor LM2596 para encender el módulo, recuerde poner en común toda la tierra del circuito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso funciono